# What does the law of large numbers say about this sample average?

Tags: random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ be independent uniform random variables with range $X_i \in [−1,2]$. What does the law of large numbers tell us about the value of 
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} \lvert X_i \rvert
$$
for large $n$?

I understand that the expected value of an individual RV should be the same as the sample average, but I'm confused how the absolute value affects the answer.

Comment: What does the law of large numbers tell you in general?

Comment: It says that the expected value of the sample average converges to the mean of a single RV for large values of n? I think?

Comment: The convergence is in probability (for the weak law) whenever the common expectation is finite. So for this question, can you see where $\frac1n\sum |X_i|$ converges to? You just have $|X_i|$ instead of $X_i$.

Comment: So when you use the formula for the mean (a+b)/2 would you take the absolute value of the range to make it (1+2)/2 = 1.5? Or would you still do (-1+2)/2 = 0.5 and THEN take the absolute value? Not sure in which step to apply it

Comment: $\frac1n\sum X_i \stackrel{P}\to E(X_1)$. Similarly $\frac1n\sum |X_i|\stackrel{P}\to E|X_1|=??$